# Sitefinity widget: Action with relative route not displayed in page where the widget is located

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, widget, sitefinity

I have an MVC widget with Index method that has RelativeRoute attribute, but when calling the route relative to its page, the content is rendered alone and ignored the template/page, which is against what is mentioned in this docs (http://docs.sitefinity.com/feather-use-the-relative-routes-api)

My Header and Footer SfPlaceholder are ignored and do not render content.

Knowing that I am using pure MVC mode and an .cshtml layout file.

Comment: what exactly do you want to do?

Comment: Giving my MVC widget a relative route to the page it is located in!

Comment: Ok, but isn't it working without it?
I mean /page would invoke the Index action,
/page/details will invoke the Details action, etc.

Comment: actually i also got this issue, the problem is the entire widget (and down below) is not rendered at all and it got `Server cannot append header after HTTP headers have been sent.` error on the log. The code for `Index()` also not invoked at all. However if the `[RelativeRoute]` attribute is removed, it works properly again.